# Why is my output different from input? (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, input, output

Input : 7182933164
Output : 2147483647
(it isnt all of the code i know there are missing } )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line;
    ifstream file("Numbers.txt");
    int num;
    cout << "Enter credit card number : " << endl;
    cin >> num;
    cout << "enterned : " << num << endl;
```

Comment: This number `7182933164` is higher than the max for a 4-byte integer. It requires use of one bit from a 5th byte, so it will fit in a 64bit integer. Try with `int64_t num`

Answer (score 2):

The value `7182933164` is such a huge number that it crosses the value of the integer it could holds (i.e. `-2147483648 to 2147483647`). Use `long` type modifier to accept such values. And if there's only positive integer required, added `unsigned` before `long`.

Do something like:

```
...
long num; // dependent upon the computer architecture
...
```

If that doesn't works, try `long long`. Although it's working fine in [OnlineGDB (example)](https://onlinegdb.com/Bybr-he6L).

Comment: @CzechBass try using `unsigned long`, if that still doesn't works then `long long` must work for you. That's working fine in TDM-GCC MinGW compiler.

Comment: @CzechBass The size of long depends on the implementation some are only 4 bytes. You can check it using sizeof(long).

Comment: Don't recommend to use implementation defined types like `long` or `long long`. Use `std::int64_t` and you can be sure about the size of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std:: string` to represent code numbers instead.